# Selenium get element from menu without ID

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am working with Selenium Web driver and need to reference am item in a javascript menu that has no id. I need to know how I can get the following web element in Selenium. I am not very proficient with javascript or HTML so any help is needed.

```
<td class="menu" colspan="2">
    <a href="javascript:Redirect('marks',0);" class="menu">
        Display Text Here
    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate this element by `xPath`:

```
//a[contains(., 'Display Text Here')]
```

so in JavaScript it will be like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Display Text Here')]")).click();
```

[Here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) you will find more information.

Answer (score 0):

To get the element with text as **Display Text Here** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *LinkText*:

  ```
  "Display Text Here"
  ```
- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  "td.menu>a.menu"
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  "//td[@class='menu']/a[@class='menu'][contains(.,'Display Text Here')]"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **linkText** :

Note that you should always choose linkText when compared to **xpath** and **cssSelector**.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Display Text Here")).click();
```